# Import Key Value Pair from Json File Consul

Tags: json, consul, consul-kv

I am new to Consul.

I am trying to import a key/value pair from Json File. (working in windows env)

But when I try to import with the following command, facing error.

Command:

```
consul.exe kv import @keyvalue.json
```

Contents:

```
{"MYVAR": "123","AnotherKey":"SomeValueHere"}
```

Error:

> Cannot unmarshal data: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []*command.kvExportEntry

Could any one suggest some ideas, in solving this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah,

Got it.

We have throw the json in this following format.

```
[        {
                "key": "europe",
                "flags": 0,
                "value": "NzQzLjE="
        },
        {
                "key": "europe/france",
                "flags": 0,
                "value": "NjYuOQ=="
        },
        {
                "key": "europe/germany",
                "flags": 0,
                "value": "ODIuNjc="
        }
]
```

Reference from: http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/07/15/first-look-at-the-key-value-store-in-consul/

Thx.

Comment: the square brackets are not needed